# Solving an equation with square roots by equating rational/non-rational parts

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A bad title I know. I'm having trouble understanding the answer to the following question:

> Solve the equation $\sqrt{6+3\sqrt2} = \sqrt a + \sqrt b$, writing a and b in the form $a + b\sqrt c$.

The answer starts by squaring both sides and then equating the parts with square roots.

$a + b = 6$ and $2\sqrt{ab} = 3\sqrt2$

I don't understand why they assume that $a + b$ is equal to $6$ because neither $a$ nor $b$ appear to be rational.

Are you supposed to assume that $a$ and $b$ have the same $b\sqrt c$ term because it doesn't ask for multiple solutions?

The answers they give are:
$a=3\pm\dfrac{3\sqrt2}{2}$,
$b=3\pm\dfrac{3\sqrt2}{2}$

Comment: The question seems to be badly posed, obviously one possible answer is $a=6+3\sqrt2$, $b=0$.

Comment: This is just a question in a practise paper so they're not too concerned with correctness. I've added the answers they gave.

Comment: @ZacPullar-Strecker As David points out the question is badly posed.  There are many correct answers, not just the two they list.  I think you should ask your teacher for clarification.

Comment: @Malcolm Yeah I see what you mean, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ and $b$
are required to be integers,
then you can equate the parts.

If not,
then,
for any $6+3\sqrt2 \ge a> 0$,
you can set
$b
=(\sqrt{6+3\sqrt2} - \sqrt a)^2
$.